# Disable scrolling UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, scroll, uipageviewcontroller

I want disable scrolling UIPageViewController until webview is loading in ViewController.
When webview is loaded, then enabled scrolling in PageViewController. 
I use:

```
for (UIScrollView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {

if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

    view.scrollEnabled = NO;
}}
```

But that disable scrolling forever.

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Inside of your if block, store away a reference to the scrollview for later use. Then, implement UIWebView's delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` and in both of those re-enable scrolling using the reference you captured earlier.

Docs for reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Comment: turns out I have to use my code above? but how do I control the scrollview in another viewcontroller? I did realize that I need to use delegate webview. But I do not know how to control my scrollview in another viewcontroller? can you show an example code?

Comment: That's very, very dependent upon how you're instantiating the view controllers, and how they're related. Make a new question with included code and I'll see if I can answer it for you. If this is the correct answer, could you accept it?

Comment: I use: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/  Only instead of pictures I use webview

Comment: Ok, that doesn't change the fact it's a different question, one that's probably been answered by someone else on SO already.

Comment: maybe there are some ideas you have about the code? Or should I wait for some other answer?